# Post form data from React handle submit function to python API?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, react-router

I'm extremely new to React and Python and just trying to do a simple post from a react form to my Python API that will interface with a mongoDB.
I have a form in react that invokes a handleSubmit function on submit. I want the handleSubmit function to POST to my Python API running on port 5000. My react app is running on port 8080.

## The handleSubmit looks like this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const axios = require('axios');
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000'

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/create', JSON.stringify(params))
        .end((error, response) => {
            if (!error && response) {
                console.log('got a valid response from the server')
            } else {
                console.log(`Error fetching data from the server: `, error)
            }
        });

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

## Python endpoint code:

```
@app.route('/api/create', methods=['POST'])
def create(self):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.args.get('exp_title'))
        return True
    return False
```

When I click the button, my python API endpoint isn't reached because react is trying to post to a route on port 8080. What am I missing?

I've tried using a regular ajax call and get the same result. At one point, I did something and got a CORS error in the browser, but I can't remember how I did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable cors, you need to install pip install -U flask-cors, 
here is the website: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
or you can define cors in proxy in your reactjs package.json like here:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Once you install cors in your python app, try this:
Python app:

```py
@app.route('/api/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def api_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('post app')
        req = request.json
        print(req)
        return jsonify(name='john')
```

React app:

```js
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { name: value };
    console.log('submit');
    console.log(value);
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => console.log(res));
  }

  function handleValue(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <section id="app">
      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleValue} />
        <button> submit </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: Your comment gave me a good place to start addressing the problem. I ended up using fetch like in your example and added header values to get pass the CORS issue.

Comment: While this is a good example with flask api, i was looking for solution with fast api.  I have added CORS settings from here : https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/ but it still gives me the CORS error.